# Does <ui:composition> go before or after <body>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am using JSF2 facelets.

I am trying to insert a piece of code from one page into the other using `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:insert>` tags.

I have page A, which includes code from page B.

`<h:form id="formIdPageA">`
...

`<h:form id="formIdPageB">`

The problem seems to be form id, since I get error:

`System error: Cannot find component with identifier ":formIdPageA:fileListId" in view.`

Here is a piece of code from page B that gets inserted into page A. Here ids can be seen:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="locationId" value = "#{PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.selectedLocationId}">
                                <p:ajax update=":formIdPageA:fileListId" listener="#{PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.LocationChangeEvent}"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{PFJobMgmtBean.outputLocationList}"/>                                
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </td>
                        <td>                                
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p:selectManyCheckbox id="fileListId" value="PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.selectedFiles"  layout="pageDirection">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.fileNames}" />  
                            </p:selectManyCheckbox>  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And this is how I insert it in page A:

```
<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Select Files" widgetVar="dlgMultiFileSelect" modal="true" height="500" width="500" resizable="false">
    <ui:insert>  
        <ui:include src="/pageB.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>  
</p:dialog>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to include page like this? Does `<ui:composition>` go before body tab or after in page B? Is this ok:

```
<body>
    <f:view>    
        <h:form id="formIdPageB">
                <ui:composition>...
```

?

**Ok, found it:**

The problem was that I used PrimeFaces component `<p:dialog>` and placed it in page A outside `<h:form>` and outside `<body>`, like this:

```
   </h:form>
 </f:view>      
</body>
<p:dialog...>        
   <ui:include src="/pageB.xhtml"/>       
</p:dialog>
```

That seems to be wrong. Now I moved `<p:dialog>` inside form and all is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used PrimeFaces component  and placed it in page A outside  and outside , like this:

```
    </h:form>
  </f:view>      
</body>
<p:dialog...>        
   <ui:include src="/pageB.xhtml"/>       
</p:dialog>
```

That seems to be wrong. Now I moved  inside the form and all is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Insert as well as composition are a tool for templating in JSF. When you use ui:insert, you create an insertion point that can be inserted (with ui:define) in the page using your template. Here is a tutorial of how to use in the right way templates and composition:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html

If I understand well, you need to reuse a block of code in page A and in page B. So I would extract the code in a separate file and include it to page A and page B.

Still if you want to put your <ui:composition> inside the <body>, it is allowed. You can see the documentation example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/composition.html

Comment: However I try it, I get error: `System error: Cannot find component with identifier ":formIdPageA:fileListId" in view.` Hmmm... any idea? How do I reference form components?

Comment: can you try formIdPageA:fileListId removing the : at the begining.

Comment: Just tried, didn't work. I am using `:` at some other places and works, so I use it here too.

Comment: can you skip the update attribute to be able to render the page. Once in the page, check in the generated html for the exact id of this element. It could be that there is a component in the middle.

Comment: Removed it. Now I get `javax.servlet.ServletException: Value of 'fileListId'must be an array or a collection`.

Comment: yes, you have the following code: value="PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.selectedFiles", and it should be something like value="#{PFMultiFileSelectMgmtBean.selectedFiles}"

Comment: Ok, this is how the component is rendered: `<table id="fileListId" class="ui-selectmanycheckbox ui-widget"></table>`

Comment: Forgot to say that the table is shown grayed out in Firebug; does that mean anything?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is strange that your id is fileListId and not formIDPageA:fileListId. Did you put prependId=false in the form?

Answer (score 1):

The `<ui:composition>` goes around the part that you want to be included. What that is, and whether it includes or excludes the `<body>`, is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is whatever I try, I get error: `System error: Cannot find component with identifier ":formIdPageA:fileListId" in view.` How do I reference form components in page B? Via form in page A?

Comment: You don't need the ui:insert. ui:include is the insert.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are using ui:insert correctly. Insert is a place holder. You need to give it a name. You then put code in that place holder using ui:define. I think for what you are trying to do you only need to remove the ui:insert tag and keep the ui:include in page A.

Comment: That didn't help. Whatever I try, I get error: `System error: Cannot find component with identifier ":formIdPageA:fileListId" in view.` How do I reference form components in page B? Via form id in page A? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I believe that since it is all sitting on form formIdPageB, you can just reference (for example)  :fileListId. If your page is rendering, you could use Firebug to help you determine the proper component ID and reference.